# Symfony 2 manyToMany clashing mapping table names

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I want to to add exclusive/inclusive products to promotion entity.
There is a clash of names when it tries to generate mapping table.

like:

promotion_product for both tables

#### promotion.orm.yml

```
manyToMany:
    productsIncluded:
        targetEntity: Acme\Bundle\DemoBundle\Entity\Product
    productsExcluded:
        targetEntity: Acme\Bundle\DemoBundle\Entity\Product
```

I am guessing that this can be achieved but having something like this:

```
manyToMany:
    productsIncluded:
        targetEntity: Acme\Bundle\DemoBundle\Entity\Product
        joinTable:
            name: promotion_included_product
            joinColumns:
                promotion_id:
                referencedColumnName: id
            inverseJoinColumns:
                product_id:
                referencedColumnName: id
    productsExcluded:
        targetEntity: Acme\Bundle\DemoBundle\Entity\Product
        joinTable:
            name: promotion_excluded_product
            joinColumns:
                promotion_id:
                referencedColumnName: id
            inverseJoinColumns:
                product_id:
                referencedColumnName: id
```

Is this a way?, or is there an easier/cleaner way that symfony auto handles this?

Let me know thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That's the way, although joinColumns and inverseJoinColumns defaults should be the same as you typed so you could shorten it to:

```
manyToMany:
    productsIncluded:
        targetEntity: Acme\Bundle\DemoBundle\Entity\Product
        joinTable:
            name: promotion_included_product
    productsExcluded:
        targetEntity: Acme\Bundle\DemoBundle\Entity\Product
        joinTable:
            name: promotion_excluded_product
```

Comment: Yea I tried that also before, but didnt work. Gave an error saying [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]                                                                              
  Notice: Undefined index: joinColumns. This is when I went defining the join columns. I guess there is no other cleaner compact version :D

Comment: Hmmm, weird, i-d expect it to just use default values as when using Annotation mapping but looks like they didn't handle that :)

Comment: well yea that's what I also thought, but I guess there might be something more to it.. :D